Internet is always slow
I decided to install Linux for the first time in my life, but I'm faced with the problem of the internet. First I installed Pop!_OS. Everything worked fine for the first half hour, then the Internet disappeared. Not finding a solution, I decided that this is a distribution problem. I installed Manjaro. The problem repeated. Now I installed Ubuntu. It's all the same.
Dell Inspiron 17r 5737 laptop. Connected via Wi-Fi to the Xiaomi AХ5400 router.
Problem: the internet works for 30 seconds-30 minutes from the moment of launch. Then the speed drops to zero. At times it appears again for a couple of seconds or minutes and falls again. Everything works on other devices at this time. Everything also works and is stable under Windows. I have a 100mbps optical fiber channel.
My experience as a Windows user tells me that the driver is rather buggy, but since I'm using Linux for the first time I can't detect it and I don't even know how.
I found advice on the internet to manually register DNS in a file. I made changes to 8.8.8.8, but nothing changed. Please help me to figure it out.

UPD info about system:


UPDATE: Found an addition! I use a bluetooth speaker for sound. As soon as the Internet starts to glitch, I turn off Bluetooth connection with speaker (bluetooth on) and everything is fine in half a second. It works for a long time, there are short-term drops for a couple of seconds and it rises again. But it's rare. If I connect the speaker - after a minute it drops again.

upd post with info. this one? or need some else?

I think you need disconnect from wifi, and connect again. If it doesn't help reboot the laptop. What is your Internet speed as provided by your telecom company?

I had a very similar issue. Instructions for determining if my fix will work for you (along with the fix itself) can be found here

Unfortunately, it didn't help. The speed still drops to zero while the speaker is connected. I can't even imagine how it is connected.

@Mahler i try re-connect and reboot. same.
https://ibb.co/thBCbkq
https://ibb.co/VCf8P4G
here screenshot of speed before and after drop =)

@Bisquit I have also Dell laptop with Ubuntu. Reconnecting helps. And I switch off the router every day. I think it's a bug in the kernel that the speed is decreasing because when I check the speed by mobile phone, it is high.

@Mahler when i use Windows - i dont have this problem, so maybe u right. But when i use ubuntu with out connected bt speaker - its work perfect. With bt buds work too 2 hour, then drop for 10sec maybe and start work again.

Kernel module rtw_8821ce.

Maybe your speaker has the same IP address as the laptop. When there exist repeated addresses the router gets confused and could not send the internet responses to the right target. ¿Do you configured a fixed IP address in Linux? When they are dynamic, Linux first check if it is used, and ask for a diferent one and avoids that situation.

Just an idea. I had to upgrade my Wi-Fi card in an old Inspiron 5537 because it didn't work with upgraded router firmware supporting some new features. sudo lshw -C network provides information on the installed Wi-Fi card. Searching for problems with that card on Linux (in combination with your router) could suggest a solution. I had a hard time finding a newer Wi-Fi card that fit the Mini-PCIE interface in my Dell but a NETELY Wireless-AC 8260HMW worked great and not too expensive.

@Fjor No, I didn't change the ip settings in linux. Windows does not have such a problem, so I have doubts.

@WalterWittel Greetings. I have two routers. One as old as the world and the new xiaomi. Both have the same problem.
I read that my laptop uses one board for wifi and bluetooth and because of this they are fighting in linux.
There is no such problem in Windows, rather due to the fact that there are separate drivers for these functions and they somehow cooperate calmly with each other.
In Linux, a dispute occurs and bluetooth simply takes the communication channel sooner. I don't know how to solve it

Any possibility the built-in WiFi is failing?  Years ago I had a similar problem with ‘random connection speed’  and the problem solved by using a WiFi dongle.  Might explain the Windows driver is buggy.
Have you tried a wired (Ethernet) connection?
...Ah!  Googled a potential clue: Bluetooth can interfere with a Wi-Fi connection , meaning when multiple devices are using this band simultaneously, their signals can overlap and disrupt each other, leading to slower speeds and potential connection drops on either network; especially noticeable when using devices like Bluetooth headphones or speakers near a Wi-Fi router.
Bluetooth uses the 2.4 GHz band (as does microwave ovens, many cordless phones), so switching your laptop to the 5 GHz band could be the solution.  ...Though distance is not a friend of the 5 GHz band.
Search using ‘Bluetooth interfere with WiFi connection’

Greetings! I also read the same thing. But everything is fine in Windows. How to partition this on linux? I have no idea how to do this.
I installed ubuntu 12.04lts. It works approx. So, some changes have occurred in the driver and now it does not work.
Tried to update gradually and saw that it deletes something there for bluetooth. Unfortunately, during the upgrade from 14 to 16, something broke and the system crashed. My laptop cant use 5Ghz https://ibb.co/fd5JT2X https://ibb.co/9YnGs6K

You installed Ubuntu 12.04; current is 24.04, though older motherboard, etc., might not be able to use -  check the OS’s requirements. Install trial option, see if works properly, then do permanent install.
Probably inviting nastygrams with following comment: I usually had problems with upgrades. I do full wipe-and-install, backing up required data plus have second machine for something usable.
As for your laptop not being able to use 5 GHz band, maybe. Built-in might be restricted to 2.4 GHz but dongle plugged into USB port should install the necessary software.  (Check compatibility.)

@Bisquit, This Windows forum mentions "Older hardware may not have the latest interference mitigation technologies.". This kernel doc addresses some of the technical solutions. Good job finding 12.04lts is OK, maybe it did mitigation in software dropped in newer kernels? I guess you may need to upgrade the Wi-Fi/Bluetooth card or use external dongle with newer kernels.

@BarryMartin Thanks for " Search using ‘Bluetooth interfere with WiFi connection’" hint, lots of good information!

I don't know if we will find a solution.
The problem is not in the hardware, because everything works in non-Linux systems.
therefore, I believe that the problem is in the drivers 100%. the question is how to find a working one and import it into the right linux environment
